# Count total of v-if output in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a code like

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
    <div v-for="(subitem, index) in subitems" :key="index" v- 
       if="item.id==subitem.item_id">
    {{count(subitem)}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
data() {
  return {
    items: [],
    subitems: [],
  }
}

watch: {

  items : async function() {
  const itm = await('get','/item')
  this.items = itm
    },

  subitems : async function() {
  const subitm = await('get','/sub_items')
  this.subitems = subitm

    },
},
</script>
```

The items and subitems array get the values of array from the api fetch in watch property. There is item id in each subitems values, Now I want count or length of for each v if output of subitem which is equal to item id. How to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put v-for and v-if on the same element can you please provide more about your array structure so i can give you the  best way but from what i have you can create do this function after getting item and subitem

```
items.foreach((element)=>{
element.subitemCount=0;
subitem.foreach(item=>{
if(element.id==item.item_id){
element.subitemCount++;}}
```

And for your vuejs you can write this

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">  {{item.subitemCount}} </div>
```

Comment: My answer will work well for you  use the script answer as function under every watcher and check before if all data is ready but it is not good to get data like this it is better to get data in the mounted instead of watcher cause watcher will fetch data again if you try to change array locally and this will make edit ui hard for you

Comment: Ok thank you. It's because of to get updated data like real time for I used watcher.

Comment: Watcher will not update data if new data is added into the db it will get data from the api if your array get changed  in vue

Comment: Yeah, watcher will not update data but it gets the new data when insert to db through api fetch. Does computed property get the data when insert data to db without check again and again like watcher?

Comment: You can push the new data in the array this way more faster then request the data again